# ¿Cómo escuchar un click dentro de un if statement?

Tags: javascript, html

Haciendo una calculadora:

```html
<div id="calculator">
        <div class="calc_keys"> 
          <input class="input" id="input0" value="0"; type="text" name="fname">
          <button id="suma" class="operator">+</button>
          <button id="resta" class="operator">-</button>
          <button id="multiplica" class="operator">*</button>
          <button id="divide" class="operator">/</button>
          <button value="7" class="key">7</button>
          <button  value="8" class="key">8</button>
          <button  value="9" class="key">9</button>
          <button  value="4" class="key">4</button>
          <button  value="5" class="key">5</button>
          <button  value="6" class="key">6</button>
          <button  value="1" class="key">1</button>
          <button  value="2" class="key">2</button>
          <button  value="3" class="key">3</button>
          <button  value="0" class="key cero">0</button>
          <button class="punto">.</button>
          <button id="borrar" class="borrar">Borrar</button>
          <button id="igual" class="igual">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

SI tengo definido este bucle:

```
 var operator = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
  function guardar(){
      valoractual1 = input0.value;
      input0.value = "0";
  }
  for (var i = 0 ; i < operator.length; i++) {
    operator[i].addEventListener('click' , guardar) ; 
  }
```

Donde `operator` es una clase que he puesto a cuatro botones diferentes, uno es sumar, otro restar, otro dividir, otro multiplicar.

Cómo puedo hacer en la siguiente función, para que según si se ha pulsado anteriormente el `operator[0]` (que sería el botón sumar), entonces sume. Si se ha pulsado el `operator[1]` (que sería el botón restar), entonces reste...etc

```
function sumaoResta(prueba1, prueba2){
  if (operator[0].onclick) {
     return Number(prueba1) + Number(prueba2)
  }
  else if ((operator[1].addEventListener('click' , guardar)) == true) {
    return Number(prueba1) - Number(prueba2)
  }
  else if () {
    return Number(prueba1) * Number(prueba2)
  }
  else if () {
    return Number(prueba1) / Number(prueba2)
  }
}
```

En los dos primeros `if` he puestos mis dos (ingenuos) intentos para ver si funcionaría pero obviamente me da `undefined`.

Después la función se llama aquí: (estoy intentando hacer una calculadora)

```js
function hazResultado(){
    valoractual2 = input0.value;
    var valorultimo = sumaoResta(valoractual1, valoractual2)
    input0.value = valorultimo;
  }
```

Comment: Donde se llama a la función sumaoresta?

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido edito el post original

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu HTML? De todas formas creo que no estás comprendiendo del todo el concepto de los addEventListener. Como su propio nombre indica, lo que haces es añadir un "Escuchador de eventos" a un determinado elemento. Por eso, yo cambiaría la lógica para que los botones de suma, resto, multiplicación y división tengan su propio "EventListener" en vez de estar comprobando en la función `sumaoResta` qué botón ha sido pulsado.

Comment: @Kiko_L Ok, añado el Html. He probado lo que dices de hacer un Listener por cada suma, resta, etc. Pero entonces no soy capaz de hacer la calculadora, porque luego en el igual, como tengo que llamar a solo una función, entonces o sólo funciona la suma, o solo la resta...etc

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que quieres identificar cual es el elemento que ocacionó el evento. Entonces tendrías que inspeccionar el argumento de la funcion pasada como eventListener:

```
target.addEventListener('click' , listener)

function listener(e /*event*/) {
    if(e.target == ...)
}
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
var operaciones = document.querySelectorAll('.operacion');
var op1 = document.getElementById("op1");
var op2 = document.getElementById("op2");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

for (var i = 0 ; i < operaciones.length; i++) {
  operaciones[i].addEventListener('click' , realizarOperacion); 
}

function realizarOperacion(e){
  if(e.target === operaciones[0]) {
     //suma
     result.value = Number(op1.value) + Number(op2.value);
  } else if(e.target === operaciones[1]) {
     //resta
     result.value = Number(op1.value) - Number(op2.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="op1">
<input type="text" id="op2">

<button class="operacion">+</button>
<button class="operacion">-</button>

<input type="text" readonly id="result">
```

En el ejemplo anterior estoy basando el comportamiento en la posicion de los botones en el documento. El primer boton declarado es el `+`, el segundo es `-`

**EDIT**

Dado que lo que quieres hacer es emular el comportamiento de una calculadora de bolsillo con un solo input, entonces tendrias que almacenar en alguna variable la operacion que se realizo anteriormente, para que al presionar `=` se calcule:

```js
var operaciones = document.querySelectorAll('.operacion');
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var igual = document.getElementById("igual");
var op1 = "", op2 = "";
var operacionActual;

for (var i = 0; i < operaciones.length; i++) {
  operaciones[i].addEventListener('click', realizarOperacion); 
}
igual.addEventListener('click', resultado);


function realizarOperacion(e){
  op1 = input.value;
  input.value = "";
  operacionActual = e.target.id;
}

function resultado() {
  op2 = input.value;
  switch(operacionActual) {
  case "suma":
     input.value = Number(op1) + Number(op2);
     break;
  case "resta":
     input.value = Number(op1) - Number(op2);
     break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="">

<button class="operacion" id="suma">+</button>
<button class="operacion" id="resta">-</button>
<button id="igual">=</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, así es mucho más simple pero me sigo atascando en como el programa sabe que es el op1 y que es el op2. Es decir, cuando se pulsa un operando entonces las teclas númericas que se hayan pulsado se guardan en op1, y después cuando se pulsa el igual las teclas númericas que se hayan pulsado se guardan en op2. Entonces claro para esto estaba haciendo dos funciones separadas pero veo que es muy confuso de esta manera.